# How can you properly instantiate a Tuple type?

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, enums, tuples

Having these enums
`ReportType, ReportField and ReportDimension` with the following specification:

Basically I have three report types and each one is kind of unique, one supports some of the ReportFields and some of the ReportDimensions (doesn't matter which), I would like to create a dictionary that has 3 KeyValuePair items (for every report type) and has tuple as value that looks like this:

```
private readonly Dictionary<ReportType, (List<ReportField>, List<ReportDimension>)> _reportTypeDimensionMappings;
```

I wanted to directly instantiate this structure but the way I intend to, gives me build errors:

```
private readonly Dictionary<ReportType, (List<ReportField>, List<ReportDimension>)> _reportTypeDimensionMappings = new Dictionary<ReportType,
        (List<ReportField>, List<ReportDimension>)>
    {
        {ReportType.Session, new (List<ReportField>, List<ReportDimension>)
            {
                new List<ReportField>
                {

                },
                new List<ReportDimension>
                {

                }
            }
        },

    };
```

**Is there an explicit good practice way to instantiate the value of a dictionary that's a Tuple ?**

Comment: i'd avoid using a value tuple here. makes your code hard to read.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're saying this, it's purpose is to be a hardcoded business mapping between ReportTypes, fields and dimensions used for validation, you see easily what you have mapped for that ReportType

Comment: i would consider using a class for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already been suggested that you shouldn't be using a Tuple here, and I agree, but to answer your question, the syntax is quite simple:

```
private readonly Dictionary<ReportType, (List<ReportField>, List<ReportDimension>)> _reportTypeDimensionMappings = 
    new Dictionary<ReportType, (List<ReportField>, List<ReportDimension>)>
    {
        {ReportType.Session, (new List<ReportField>(), new List<ReportDimension>()) }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a class would be better suited for what you need.  You could create a class called `Report` that contains your `List<ReportField>` and `List<ReportDimension>` properties.

Tuples are useful for when you need a short-lived, relatively-small collection of values or objects to be treated as one thing (i.e. a return from a method), but there's really not much cost to creating a dedicated class for these types of things either.  As Daniel A. White pointed out in your comments section, it makes your code harder to read, and given you don't need much of a reason to create a class for any purpose, I'd say any reason is good enough.

Comment: Well, solving this is was not a problem, I thought about your resolve, and also you can solve this with an extra dictionary and each dictionary will be mapped to only one List<ReportField>/List<ReportDimension>. My point was to see if there's a solution on how can you directly instantiate that tuple

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Tuple object by calling `Tuple t = Tuple.Create(object1, object2);` then you can get the values by `t.Item1` for `object1` and `t.Item2` for `object2`

Comment: With C# 7 it's even simpler to create a tuple: (object 1, object 2).  Note this is a *value*-type tuple as compared to the `System.Tuple`, which is a reference type.